# GDebi Package Installer Does Nothing

Tags: package-management, software-installation, gdebi

No errors and GDebi opens but when I select Install Package, nothing happens. It WAS working a few days ago with the same .deb but not today and a system reboot did not help. I am not sure what else to try!

Comment: Try using apt directly: `sudo apt install /path/to/file_name.deb`. If it fails, post the entire output in your question.

Comment: Thank you, that got it installed and it didn’t even prompt to uninstall the old version first as it did before when GDebi was working. However, it doesn’t solve the actual problem of why GDevi doesn’t work so why is that? Also, the regular Software installer isn’t working either and just spins and spins so can these two things be related?

Comment: "Why": Check /var/log/syslog and /var/log/apt/term.log for clues. Yes, problems with Ubuntu Software might be related. Check the same log files for clues..

Comment: How exactly do you run GDebi? Do you have any errors while running `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: GDebi runs by default when double-clicking a deb file and no errors there. It opens as it should but the Install Package button does nothing. That is, the GDebi dialog disappears and nothing else happens. The updates mentioned do not generate any errors either and run properly although the system was already up to date.